# Qt 5.5 development, Qt 3 replacements?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with Qt 5.5 and recently received a book from Amazon "Programming with Qt", I didn't realise at the time I ordered the book that it covers the older Qt 3.

Is there a guide on porting Qt 3 to Qt 5.5 for example:

```
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setMainWidget()
```

What has setMainWidget been replaced with?

Comment: Return the book. You don't really need a book for Qt, there is plenty of resources available on the internet for free. Qt 3 was released 15 years ago, it is a shame to still sell book for it. Qt 3 and Qt 5 are very very different. Porting 4 to 5 maybe, but 3 to 5 is just too much of a gap. Just start off with 5.

Comment: If your `C++` knowledge is decent, you should be able to pick up `Qt` pretty quick by just looking at the docs and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set a main widget in Qt 4/5. You simply:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  have returned the book and will be ordering another on Qt5 (http://www.amazon.com/Qt5-Blueprints-Symeon-Huang/dp/1784394610)